# Cache conscious SIMD matrix multiply of unsigned integers

Tags: c, matrix, sse, simd

**The goal of the code review by order of importance (i.e. What I hope to hear from you):**

1. I've verified correctness using a straightforward matrix multiply function though *I am open to those who want to verify correctness*.
2. I'm just starting to learn about the benefits and challenges posed by coding things in SSE, while at the same time, keeping in mind hardware level caching. As such, *input on room for efficiency gains would be greatly appreciated.*
3. Coding style. Obviously there is always some room for improvement here so any thoughts on this is greatly appreciated.

Some notes on SSE:

1. Writing out from SSE is always expensive, especially when trying to extract some but not all of the values in the vector lanes (using for example `_mm_extract_epi32`
2. Some SSE instructions are quite expensive. For example `_mm_hadd_epi32` is quite expensive, requiring that I find ways to minimize its use.

**The goal of the code:**

The function below is me trying to learn caching and SSE. I've done both to a limited extent, separately. And this is just me trying to combine the two.

The function performs a matrix multiply on matrices `a` and `b`, both of size `n` x `n` and saves the results in `c`. All of these matrices are 16 byte aligned in memory.

It first transposes `b` into `t` so the data in matrix `b`, now `t`, can be accessed in row-major order.

It then reads `block` number rows of `a`, and iterates those rows over `block` number of rows in `t` using SSE to perform the multiplication and summation. This "blocking" is the bit that helps with caching and is a typical cache optimization technique. These are implemented using the `ii` and `jj` loops.

The main inner loop is the `i` and `j` loops. The `i` loop iterates over each row in each block in `a` and the `j` loop iterates over each row in each block in `t`.

The `j` loop accumulates 4 rows worth of products in the correct order into a single SSE register before writing out the results to `c`.

Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
   int fast_matrix_multiply_simd(uint32_t * a, 
                                 uint32_t * b, 
                                 uint32_t * c, 
                                 size_t n, 
                                 size_t block){

        // for simplicity, the following limitations are enfoced
        // block should be a multiple of 4
        if (block % 4 != 0){
            return -1;
        }

        // n should be a multiple of block
        if (n % block != 0){
            return -1;
        }

        // create a temporary transpose matrix -- created in dynamic memory
        uint32_t * t = transpose_matrix_block(b, n);
        if (!t){
            return -1;
        }

        __m128i * m128_a, * m128_t, * m128_c;
        size_t en = n;

        // number of iterations of 128bit loads per row
        size_t m128_count = (n * sizeof(uint32_t) * 8)/128;

        // need a temporary place to store result vectors
        // which will be summed
        __m128i loaded_temp[4];

        // values that update at each loop
        size_t at_i, at_j, i, j, k, ii_block, jj_block;

        // blocking for cache concious purposes using the outer loop
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < en; ii += block){
            ii_block = ii + block;
            for (size_t jj = 0; jj < en; jj += block){
                jj_block = jj + block;

                // main inner loop, i and j loop over rows of a and t respectively
                for (i = ii; i < ii_block; ++i){

                    at_i = n * i;
                    m128_a = (__m128i*)&(a[at_i]);
                    m128_c = (__m128i*)&(c[at_i + jj]);

                    for (j = jj; j < jj_block; j+=4){
                        at_j = n * j;
                        m128_t = (__m128i*)&(t[at_j]);

                        // essentially, unroll an inner loop that multiplies a row
                        // in the "a" matrix by 4 rows in the "t" matrix, to take 
                        // advantage of 4 SSE lanes, Accumulate the sums of each
                        // in a single SSE vector, write into "c" matrix, then
                        // move on to the next block in "t"

                        loaded_temp[0] = _mm_set_epi32(0,0,0,0);
                        for (k = 0; k < m128_count; ++k){
                            loaded_temp[0] = _mm_add_epi32(loaded_temp[0],_mm_mullo_epi32(m128_a[k], m128_t[k]));
                        }

                        m128_t = (__m128i*)(t + at_j + n);
                        loaded_temp[1] = _mm_set_epi32(0,0,0,0);
                        for (k = 0; k < m128_count; ++k){
                            loaded_temp[1] = _mm_add_epi32(loaded_temp[1],_mm_mullo_epi32(m128_a[k], m128_t[k]));
                        }

                        m128_t = (__m128i*)(t + at_j + n + n);
                        loaded_temp[2] = _mm_set_epi32(0,0,0,0);
                        for (k = 0; k < m128_count; ++k){
                            loaded_temp[2] = _mm_add_epi32(loaded_temp[2],_mm_mullo_epi32(m128_a[k], m128_t[k]));
                        }

                        m128_t = (__m128i*)(t + at_j + n + n + n);
                        loaded_temp[3] = _mm_set_epi32(0,0,0,0);
                        for (k = 0; k < m128_count; ++k){
                            loaded_temp[3] = _mm_add_epi32(loaded_temp[3],_mm_mullo_epi32(m128_a[k], m128_t[k]));
                        }

                        // combine first two
                        loaded_temp[0] = _mm_hadd_epi32(loaded_temp[0], loaded_temp[1]);
                        loaded_temp[0] = _mm_hadd_epi32(loaded_temp[0], loaded_temp[0]);
                        loaded_temp[0] = _mm_and_si128(_mm_set_epi32(-1,0,0,-1),loaded_temp[0]);

                        // combine second 2
                        loaded_temp[2] = _mm_hadd_epi32(loaded_temp[2], loaded_temp[3]);
                        loaded_temp[2] = _mm_hadd_epi32(loaded_temp[2], loaded_temp[2]);
                        loaded_temp[2] = _mm_and_si128(_mm_set_epi32(-1,0,0,-1),loaded_temp[2]);

                        // combine totals
                        loaded_temp[0] = _mm_hadd_epi32(loaded_temp[0], loaded_temp[2]);

                        *m128_c = loaded_temp[0];
                        ++m128_c;
                    } // ends j loop
                } // ends i loop
                // end main inner loop

            } // ends jj block loop
        } // ends ii block loop

        free(t); // Free the transposed matrix since this is no longer needed
        return 0;
    }
```